# How implement and build Angular dynamic forms using real data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am struggling with the implementation of dynamically creating an Angular form from `JSON` data.

I have used the [example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) on the Angular site as reference, and I got this to work with the mock data service, but I am battling with the implementation when using real data.

**The Angular mock data method looks like this (using static data to build the `form` and the `formFields`):**

```
getFields() {
    let fields: FormBase<any>[] = [

      new DropdownField({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          { key: 'solid', value: 'Solid' },
          { key: 'great', value: 'Great' },
          { key: 'good', value: 'Good' },
          { key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven' }
        ],
        order: 3
      }),

      new TextboxField({
        key: 'firstName',
        label: 'First name',
        value: 'Bombasto',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      }),

      new TextboxField({
        key: 'emailAddress',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'email',
        order: 2
      })
    ];

    return fields.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
}
```

**My real `array` of data `objects` would look something like this (just a single `object` to illustrate):**

```
[  
   {  
      Name:"Pallet Quantity",
      Type:"Integer",
      Required: false,
      Units:[  
         {  
            Name:"Kilograms"
         },
         {  
            Name:"Tonnes"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Here is my attempt to implement the Angular `FormBase<any>[]`, `new DropdownField` and `new TextboxField` using my data:**

```
  createFields(dataArray) {
    let order = 0;
    let newArray = [];
    let tempArray = [];
    let modifiedArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      let controlType = null;
      switch (dataArray[i].Type) {
        case 'Integer':
          controlType = 'number';
          break;
        default: controlType = 'text';
          break;
      };

      if (dataArray[i].Units.length > 0) {
        modifiedArray = [];
        tempArray = dataArray[i].Units;
        tempArray.forEach(unit => {
          modifiedArray.push({
            key: unit.Name,
            value: unit.Name
          });
        });
      }

      newArray.push({
        key: dataArray[i].Name,
        placeholder: dataArray[i].Name,
        order: order++,
        required: dataArray[i].Required,
        controlType: controlType,
        options: modifiedArray
      });
    }
    return this.createFormAndFields(newArray);
  }

  createFormAndFields(newArray) {

    let fields: FormBase<any>[] = [];
    let dropDownArray;
    let textBoxArray;

    for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      if (newArray[i].options.length > 0) {
        dropDownArray = [
          new DropdownField(newArray[i])
        ]
      }
      if (newArray[i].options.length === 0) {
        textBoxArray = [
          new TextboxField(newArray[i]),
        ]
      }
    }
    dropDownArray.push(...textBoxArray);
    fields.push(dropDownArray);
    return fields.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
```

I am not getting errors, but no forms or fields gets created. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your suggestions and help.

Comment: what errors are appearing?

Comment: You should step through this in a debugger and ensure that no values are unexpected.

Comment: could you create a demo showcasing your issue, much easier to help :)

Comment: Hey all. Thanks for the comments. I get absolutely no errors. I do step through the debugger, and everything seem right. I think it has to do with the way I instantiate this `let fields: FormBase<any>[] = [];`, and then simply pushing my `fields` array into it. I don't know. My data match up with my models etc. I am at a lost.